# SwiftUI use searchable modifier with an enter/search button

Tags: swiftui

I want to use the searchable modifier in swiftui but am calling a webapi and don't want to do so on every character. Most of the examples I have seen, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZhqnd1kPC8) and [this one](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-search-bar-to-filter-your-data#:%7E:text=SwiftUI%E2%80%99s%20searchable%20%28%29%20modifier%20lets%20us%20place%20a,some%20view%20inside%20a%20navigation%20view%2C%20like%20this%3A) search on each character (or potentially a certain number of characters) but I want to search only on enter/search key. I have not seen an example of this. Has anybody done this before?

I'm new to SwiftUI, so there may be a simple answer I'm missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.onSubmit(of: .search)`

```
ContentView()
    .searchable(text: $text) {
        MySearchSuggestions()
    }
    .onSubmit(of: .search) {
        fetchResults()
    }
```

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10176

Comment: Any way to make it search for a bank string? It doesn't seem to work if I just hit enter w/o any value.